# Facebook Application Using GWT

Tags: gwt, facebook

Does anyone have experience writing a Facebook application using GWT with GAE?  I'm new to GWT/GAE and the web world but not new to Java and am having some slight issues integrating with the Facebook API.

Currently I've settled on utilizing a filter to authenticate the request to my main servlet against Facebook to ensure proper credentials are passed and to generate the JSON client that is then added to the user session. The servlet redirects the client to the main entrypoint which validates against an authentication servlet to guarantee the presence of the client in the session to prevent against spoofing of the credentials within the html request.

I took this route because I couldn't find a means by which to redirect the client to Facebook's login from the authentication servlet if called directly from the entrypoint page. However, aside from the fact that this seems impractical I appear to lose the session attributes once the entrypoint submits to the authentication servlet (or any other). I've ensured I have sessions enabled but apparently am doing something wrong.

Does anyone have insight into what I've overlooked or know of any decent GWT/Facebook tutorials out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: while I know GWT very well, I haven't yet created any GWT app for Facebook. That being said:

- [This blog post](http://www.mushrappa.org/?p=6) could interest you. He goes over the steps necessary to create a GWT app for Facebook. Ozgur also gives advice about authenticating your Facebook users.
- [This other post](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/12/put-your-gwt-app-on-facebook-in-10.html) from the GWT blog could interest you.
- [This google code project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/) might also be of interest.

Finally, you might find some code samples using [Google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=facebook+com.google.gwt+lang%3Ajava). I often use this feature and it's great!

*(BTW, you just made me consider using my "GWT skillz" to create a facebook app too, might be fun!)*

Comment: Thanks. There's a lot of good information there. As far as Facebook goes, it's been pretty fun so far but there's definitely something to be desired from their existing API. Good luck.